# How to perform a 2D Fast Fourier Transform in c++

Tags: c++, fft

I saw there was a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208974/how-to-perform-fft2d-fast-fourier-transform-2d-r-g-b-color-component) about this topic, but without any reply.
How to write a function that performs the **2D Fast Fourier Transform** for a given image f?
It is possible to assume that the width = 2^m, height = 2^n for some integers m and n, and the input image is already properly padded.
**Input:** f - An 2D Image represented in Complex Numbers
**Output:** F - The transformed coefficients, also represented in Complex Numbers

```
void FFT2D(Complex<double> *f, Complex<double> *F, int width, int height)
{

}
```

For everyone who think I want you to program it for me:
I don't. Just want some theoretical explanation of how this should work

Comment: This isn't a question, it is a request for free work.

Comment: I didn't ask to write it for me. just to give me some directions of how to do it logically

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [FFTW library](http://www.fftw.org/) to perform this:

```
#include <fftw.h>

void FFT2D(Complex<double> *f, Complex<double> *F, int width, int height){   
  fftw_plan p = fftw_plan_dft_2d(width, height, f, F, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);            
  fftw_execute(p); 
  fftw_destroy_plan(p);
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand the answer... Can you please explain the steps I should have for it? For example what is actually fftw_forward and fftw_estimate

Comment: Rather than write your own FFT, it is probably best to use an FFT library. FFTW is the easiest to use. See http://fftw.org/ and http://fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs.html#Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs for an example

Answer (score 2):

I doubt anyone's going to write a FFT implementation for you. It's non-trivial and time-consuming (you've also shown zero effort).

Do you understand the math behind it? If you understand the math behind it, you need to look at various FFT algorithms (Cooley Tukey comes to mind) and simply implement them. Also, this smells like a homework problem.

But since you asked, here's a C implementation of a DFT and FFT courtesy of Google: http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/dft/

PS: Do you want to write an A* implementation for *me*?